# Passing arrays from C++ to Java using Swig directors, the up call

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a C++ class with a virtual method. I'm using directors and I sub-classed the C++ class in Java. This class is for receiving callbacks from the C++ code. So the Java class is then passed to C++ and C++ calls methods on it (upcalls to Java). There are array arguments (or pointer arrays, I've tried both) and they get converted to SWIGTYPE_p_double.

I would like to have a Java side type signature of double[] and of course have the contents of the array in that double[] argument (copying the contents is fine).

How can I do this?

I've tried it with the following code which I lifted from some email lists:

c_backend.i:

```
%module(directors="1") c_backend

%{
#include "c_backend.h"
%}

%typemap(directorin, descriptor="[D") (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) { 
   jdoubleArray jd = (jenv)->NewDoubleArray($2); 
   (jenv)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(jd, 0, $2, (jdouble *)$1); 
   $input = jd; 
} 
%typemap(directorargout) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) 
%{(jenv)->GetDoubleArrayRegion($input, 0, $2, (jdouble *)$1); %} 

%feature("director") CallbackHandler;

%include "c_backend.h"
```

c_backend.h:

```
#ifndef CALLBACK_HANDLER_H
#define CALLBACK_HANDLER_H

#include <stdio.h>


class CallbackHandler {
  public:
    virtual ~CallbackHandler() {}
    virtual void statusUpdate( double *params, size_t size ) {
        printf("in C++ statusUpdate\n");
    }
};


class Server {
  public:
    void doSomething( CallbackHandler * );
};

#endif
```

c_backend.cpp:

```
#include "c_backend.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Server::doSomething( CallbackHandler *ch ) {
    double *params = (double *)malloc(3*sizeof(double));
    params[0] = 1.1;
    params[1] = 2.2;
    params[2] = 3.3;
    printf("In doSomthing\n");
    ch->statusUpdate(params,3);
    printf("exiting doSomthing\n");
}
```

JavaFrontend.java:

```
public class JavaFrontend {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CBackend");
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFCallbackHandler jf = new JFCallbackHandler();
        new Server().doSomething(jf);
    }

    public static class JFCallbackHandler extends CallbackHandler {
        public void statusUpdate( double params[], long size ) {
            System.out.println("Java got params: "+params);
        }
    }
}
```

And a Makefile to compile:

```
JAVA_INCLUDE=-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin

all:
    c++ -c c_backend.cpp
    swig -java -c++ $(JAVA_INCLUDE) c_backend.i
    c++ $(JAVA_INCLUDE) -c c_backend_wrap.cxx
    c++ -dynamiclib -o libCBackend.jnilib *.o -framework JavaVM
    javac *.java

clean:
    rm -rf *.class *.o *_wrap.cxx *_wrap.h Server.java SWIGTYPE*.java c_backend*.java CallbackHandler.java
```

Swig -version:

> SWIG Version 3.0.8
>
> Compiled with clang++ [x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0]
>
> Configured options: +pcre
>
> Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further
>   information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working with a bit of effort. The typemaps you found as a starting point are reasonable, but I think not complete. I don't think you can realistically write directorin/directorargout typemaps without having a matching in/jtype/jstype/jni/javadirectorin/javain one, because you very rapidly end up with mismatched expectations between various fragments of generated code. (The director code can call the regular Java class as well and also be called by it).

Also, I think it's much better to use a multiargument typemap to condense the pointer and size arguments down to a single argument inside Java given that length is implicitly an attribute of an array in Java.

So here's a quick summary of what I had to do to make it work:

1. Firstly, your existing typemaps won't get applied to your code because they match on both argument type and argument name. `%apply` is the neat way to do this, particularly for multi-argument typemaps like these.
2. Secondly, added corresponding typemaps for in rather than just directorin.
3. Thirdly, added typemaps to pass `double[]` all the way through from C++ to Java via the proxy.
4. Finally, because the type is now just `double[]` and an implicit size the test case needed updating to make sure it remained an override instead of an overload. For good measure I added `@Override`.

And some stylistic changes I made because they're better code:

1. Removed the casts from the typemap inputs to jdouble. At best they should be a no-op (`double*`->`jdouble*`), but at worst they're going to hide something untoward.
2. Set the typemaps up to be within a block of their own. This means you can use the same typemap twice on the same function without clashing local variable names. (Although I removed the local variable in the end anyway)
3. Used SWIG's JCALLx macros - this is clearly C++ code, but it's a habit I try to keep in when writing SWIG code.

So in the end your SWIG interface looked like this:

```
%module(directors="1") c_backend

%{
#include "c_backend.h"
%}

%typemap(jstype) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) "double[]"
%typemap(jtype) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) "double[]"
%typemap(jni) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(javadirectorin) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) "$jniinput"
%typemap(javain) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) "$javainput"
%typemap(in,numinputs=1) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) {
  // Note the NULL here if you don't want to be making changes visible
  $1 = JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
  $2 = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input);
}
%typemap(freearg) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) {
  // Swap 0 for JNI_ABORT if you don't want to make changes visible
  JCALL3(ReleaseDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, $1, 0); 
}
%typemap(directorin,descriptor="[D") (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) { 
  $input = JCALL1(NewDoubleArray, jenv, $2); 
  JCALL4(SetDoubleArrayRegion, jenv, $input, 0, $2, $1); 
} 
%typemap(directorargout) (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) {
  (jenv)->GetDoubleArrayRegion($input, 0, $2, $1); 
} 

%feature("director") CallbackHandler;

%apply (double *DOUBLE, size_t LENGTH) { (double *params, size_t size) };

%include "c_backend.h"
```

Which was sufficient to make your test case work correctly with the aforementioned change to make it override instead of overload now.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code! It's been a while since I had to work with this, but I'm back in this problem and tried your solution. It works for me.

Comment: It took me just a moment to realize I needed to remove the size argument from the Java code. I know you mention it here, but it didn't click for me immediately since the code wasn't shown. I'm adding this comment in case other readers have the same problem... don't forget to update the Java sub-class.

Comment: Is there a reason `JCALL` is being used to call the JNI methods in four places but in a fifth place `jenv` is used directly (see the line `(jenv)->GetDoubleArrayRegion(...)`). I'm wondering if this was a mistake or if it is intentional. Maybe `JCALL5` should be used???

Comment: I have now integrated this solution into my project. It works great! I made a couple small modifications for our particular use case, but the solution is almost identical. So this really is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I missed that one and only tested  one a C++ compiler!